Will adding tools:node="false" in AD_ID permission (from Firebase SDK) stops detecting/asking AD_ID in Google play console's App Content section?
Will Google play console stop detecting permission OR asking for Advertising ID in App content Section if i will add tools:node="remove" on com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID permission into AndroidManifest.xml file (AD_ID detecting from Facebook SDK)?
I am trying to remove unused AD_ID permission adding by Facebook SDK which detects on Google play console in App Content section while uploading App.
I don't want that Google Play Console detect Advertising ID (AD_ID permission) while uploading new release build file after adding tools:node="remove" in AD_ID permission in android manifest file
If anyone has knowledge about this, please message with appropriate answer.
Thank in advance

add this line of code in your apps manifest file and then reupload the app.
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" tools:node="remove"/>


I already added it in manifest file but the question is that the Google Play Console stop detecting AD_ID or advertising ID while uploading new release build .aab file.

For my app I solved it by inserting the following line in the Manifest
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" tools:node="remove"/> 
</manifest>


I already added it in manifest file but the question is that the Google Play Console stop detecting AD_ID or advertising ID while uploading new release build .aab file.

In your question I noticed tools:node="false" while to solve the problem you need tools:node="remove"

Sorry my mistake, i used the same tools:node="remove".
It removes AD_ID permission from Manifest Merger section but will it stop detecting AD_ID from Google Play Console while uploading new release build?

Yes, with my app the problem was solved
